# Array of object not getting sorted in the correct order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, typescript, lodash

I have an array of objects, and I'm trying to sort the array by a date property on the object. I'm using lodash function orderBy so I can pass an ascending or descending order.

```js
var searchObj = [{id: 1, postDate: '2/24/2016 5:08 PM'},
                 {id: 2, postDate: '3/14/2012 8:39 AM'},
                 {id: 3, postDate: '3/23/2016 1:56 AM'},
                 {id: 4, postDate: '5/9/2016 8:14 AM'},
                 {id: 5, postDate: '11/11/2016 05:26 PM'},
                 {id: 6, postDate: '05/19/2016 03:40 AM'},
                 {id: 7, postDate: '5/10/2016 9:23 PM'},
                 {id: 8, postDate: '11/07/2017 01:07 PM'},
                 {id: 9, postDate: '6/7/2011 9:20 AM'},
                 {id: 10, postDate: '11/03/2015 12:03 PM'}];

console.log(searchObj);

searchObj = _.orderBy(searchObj, [obj =>
  new Date(obj['postDate'].trim()).getTime() / 10000
], ['asc']);

console.log(searchObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

But for some reason the order is not always correct so on my sorted array I would have this.

1. 2/24/2016 5:08 PM
2. 3/14/2012 8:39 AM
3. 3/23/2016 1:56 AM
4. 5/9/216 8:14 AM
5. 5/10/2016 9:23 PM
6. 6/7/2011 9:20 AM

Any idea on how can I fix that so its sorted correctly?

Comment: Can you make this a runnable example?

Comment: ^^ not least because the examples given aren't strings in a format that `new Date` is specified to parse correctly.

Comment: Snippets are for **runnable** examples. For just a code block, use a code block (`{}`). More here about doing snippets: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha

Comment: In Chrome this is returning expected results, as @T.J.Crowder mentioned that date string format `M[M]/D[D]/YYYY` is not a known format to parse via the specification so it's dependent on how the browser handles it: [*"A string representing an RFC2822 or (a variant of) ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected)."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Really? For me on Chrome, it puts `05/19/2016` (May 19th 2016) between `11/11/2016` (Nov 11 2016) and `5/10/2016` (May 10th 2016) -- almost certainly because of parsing issues. Also, beware that MDN page, even RFC2822 isn't **specified** anywhere, only the not-quite-ISO-8601 format defined by the spec.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Are you looking at the second console log result?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: **:-D** It would appear not, no. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your strings aren't in a format that `new Date` is [required to parse](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), and implementations will fall back on ["...any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats..."](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date.parse) — the danger being that it may apply different interpretations to different strings you give it, even though **you** know they're all in the same format.

You need to parse your strings yourself, and use the `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, sec, ms)` constructor instead. *(I'm not writing it here; it's trivial, and there are lots of examples on SO for doing it.)*

Comment: I will see if I can change the date to come in the correct format otherwise I will try parsing the date

Answer (score 0):

Why use lodash? You don't need it.

```
function sortBy(list, columnName, descending){
  let res = list.sort(function(a, b){
    return a[columnName].getTime() - b[columnName].getTime();
  });
  if(descending){
    return res.reverse();
  } else {
    return res;
  }
}
```

Where descending is a boolean, true for ascending, false for descending sort.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/robbiemilejczak/kcuq6td5/

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, just remove [] from second parameter from _.orderBy.

```js
var searchObj = [{id: 1, postDate: '2/24/2016 5:08 PM'},
                 {id: 2, postDate: '3/14/2012 8:39 AM'},
                 {id: 3, postDate: '3/23/2016 1:56 AM'},
                 {id: 4, postDate: '5/9/2016 8:14 AM'},
                 {id: 5, postDate: '11/11/2016 05:26 PM'},
                 {id: 6, postDate: '05/19/2016 03:40 AM'},
                 {id: 7, postDate: '5/10/2016 9:23 PM'},
                 {id: 8, postDate: '11/07/2017 01:07 PM'},
                 {id: 9, postDate: '6/7/2011 9:20 AM'},
                 {id: 10, postDate: '11/03/2015 12:03 PM'}];

console.log(searchObj);

searchObj = _.orderBy(searchObj, obj =>
  new Date(obj['postDate'].trim()).getTime() / 10000
, 'asc');

console.log(searchObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: orderBy can accept an array of iteratees so passing the function inside an array will still work.